# Deleting an entire row based on the text in a cell of that row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA in order to delete an entire row based on the *approximate* content of a cell of that same row. I have found this for the exact content:

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnOwner()
    Dim RowToTest As Long
    For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        With Cells(RowToTest, 5)
            If .Value = "John" _
            Or .Value = "Jerry" _
            Or .Value = "Steve" _
            Or .Value = "Robert" _
            Or .Value = "Sarah" _
            Or .Value = "Leonard" _
            Or .Value = "Darryl" _
            Or .Value = "Mike" _
            Or .Value = "Martin" _
            Then _
            Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next RowToTest
End Sub
```

However, wildcards don't seem to work here. For instance, I've tried:

```
If .Value = "Jo*" _
Or .Value = "*err*" _
```

But this does not work. I Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Use [*Like*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) Operator. So, first condition equates to `If .Value2 Like "Jo*"` and so on with the rest of your conditions.

Comment: ugh... I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks very much, it worked. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "like" instead of "=".

```
 If .Value like "Jo*" _
     Or .Value like "*err*" _
```